# How to sort a dictionary according to it's keys in Julia?

Tags: julia

I want to sort the following dictionary in Julia in way that the key values are printed in alphabetical order of the key names.

```
fruits = Dict("Mangoes" => 5, "Pomegranates" => 4, "Apples" => 8);
```

On executing the above code and entering `fruits`, I get the output as:

```
fruits
Dict{String,Int64} with 3 entries:
  "Pomegranates" => 4
  "Apples"       => 8
  "Mangoes"      => 5
```

However, I expect the following result:

```
Apples       => 8
Mangoes      => 5
Pomegranates => 4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because [dictionaries](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Dictionaries-1) in Julia (`Dict`) are not ordered: each dictionary maintains a *set* of keys. The order in which one gets keys when one iterates on this set is not defined, and can vary as one inserts new entries. There are two things that one can do to ensure that one iterates on dictionary entries in a specific order.

The first method is to get the set of keys (using [`keys`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.keys)) and sort it yourself, as has been proposed in another answer:

```
julia> fruits = Dict("Mangoes" => 5, "Pomegranates" => 4, "Apples" => 8);

julia> for key in sort!(collect(keys(fruits)))
           val = fruits[key]
           println("$key => $val")
       end
Apples => 8
Mangoes => 5
Pomegranates => 4
```

That being said, if the order of keys is important, one might want to reflect that fact in the type system by using an *ordered* dictionary ([OrderedDict](https://juliacollections.github.io/OrderedCollections.jl/latest/ordered_containers.html#OrderedDicts-and-OrderedSets-1)), which is a data structure in which the order of entries is meaningful. More precisely, an `OrderedDict` preserves the order in which its entries have been inserted.

One can either create an `OrderedDict` from scratch, taking care of inserting keys in order, and the order will be preserved. Or one can create an `OrderedDict` from an existing `Dict` simply using `sort`, which will sort entries in ascending order of their key:

```
julia> using OrderedCollections

julia> fruits = Dict("Mangoes" => 5, "Pomegranates" => 4, "Apples" => 8);

julia> ordered_fruits = sort(fruits)
OrderedDict{String,Int64} with 3 entries:
  "Apples"       => 8
  "Mangoes"      => 5
  "Pomegranates" => 4

julia> keys(ordered_fruits)
Base.KeySet for a OrderedDict{String,Int64} with 3 entries. Keys:
  "Apples"
  "Mangoes"
  "Pomegranates"
```

Comment: Good answer, could you add some reference and mention the fact that in Julia, dicts are not ordered? This would make clear why is another type of Dict needed.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer to include more details.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
fruits = Dict("Mangoes" => 5, "Pomegranates" => 4, "Apples" => 8);
for key in sort(collect(keys(fruits)))
  println("$key => $(fruits[key])")
end
```

It gives this result:

```
Apples => 8
Mangoes => 5
Pomegranates => 4
```